# Common Interceptor/Handler for SOAP Webservices

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, cxf, interceptor

If you are using RESTful Webservices, we can have a filter which can filter any request based on pattern and filter any RESTful request. But if we are using SOAP web services, we cannot use that filter to get any information out of SOAP request, because SOAP request is sent as payload and can be read only once.

Is there any way we can declare a interceptor in CXF or Handler in JAX-WS which can intercept all SOAP requests or intercept based on regex pattern like * etc..

The requirement is to basically take the authorization token from every SOAP request's header and set it into thread context for future use. The above mentioned way looks like the only solution because we don't want to add a interceptor to every service manually.

Another solution is to add the authorization token to httpheader and collect it using filter. Is there any way we can add http header to a soap payload?

Please provide solution or suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To attach interceptor to all endpoints use cxf:bus

```
   <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="inWsMessageInterceptor"/>
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="outWsMessageInterceptor"/>
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
        <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
            <ref bean="outWsMessageInterceptor"/>
        </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
    </cxf:bus>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use interceptor to access the message

```
public class CustomInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor<SOAPMessage> {


    public CustomInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.RECEIVE);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SOAPMessage message) throws Fault {


        //Use header to access the element, as I believe generally header is used carry authorization details 
        message.getSOAPHeader();

        //Can be used to access body information
        message.getSOAPBody();      

    }

}
```

You can add in config file as below

```
<jaxws:endpoint>

    <jaxws:inInterceptors>
           <ref bean="custInterceptor"/>
        </jaxws:inInterceptors>

</jaxws:endpoint>

<bean id="custInterceptor" class="com.kp.CustomInterceptor">
```

Comment: If you look at the question carefully, I am looking for a interceptor which intercepts all endpoints.. From your example I can create an interceptor for only one endpoint.